# Create interface that has optional unknown properties of an unknown type

Tags: typescript

```
interface Example {
    value?: string
    [prop: string]: any
}

const xxx: Example = { name: 'Thomas' }

const v = xxx.name
```

Adding "any" here actually removes the inferred "string" type on name that would otherwise be there if `xxx` was not assigned to Example.

Is there any way to have a interface or type that passed the inferred type?

Comment: `type Example = {
  value?: string;
} & {
  [prop: string]: any
}` PS: it's either `name?` or `xxx.value` is it?

Comment: @zerkms This would remove the inferred string type from the `name` prop, same as the interface above.

Comment: There is no type inference there - you explicitly assign the type.

Comment: `const xxx = { name: 'Thomas' }` has inferred typing without explicitly assigning the type. I am only trying to add information about `value` and not remove the inferred typing for the rest of the object.

Comment: Sure, here it's inferred. But in your original code - `const xxx: Example` you declare the type explicitly. And that type holds the name `property` or type `any`. What you request makes no sense. You cannot have `xxx.name` as `string` simply because it's not declared as such. Do you really need to explicitly set `xxx`'s type?

Comment: There's a price to pay for flexibility. If you want type safety, assign types. If you want any type for any property, you forgo type safety.

Comment: I think the question is looking for a way to narrow the inferred type of the object literal, by adding the optional `value` property, but without having to write a type annotation that says `name` is a string, given that the object literal already declares name with a string value. That does make sense as something you might want to do.

Comment: @kaya3 it looks odd though: "is looking for a way to narrow the inferred type of the object literal" --- why type it explicitly at all then.

Comment: @zerkms I don't really follow your question - OP wants a way to write something similar to `const xxx = { name: 'Thomas' };` and have `xxx` be of type `{ name: string, value?: string }`, so some sort of extra code (e.g. a type annotation) has to be added, but ideally without redundantly having to annotate that `name` is still a string. That's how I understand the question.

Comment: `const xxx = { name: 'Thomas' };` --- `xxx` is already compatible with `{ name: string, value?: string }` type, there is no need to type it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a generic `Record` type:

```js
type Example<K extends PropertyKey, V> = Record<K, V> & {
    // non-generic interface properties go here
    value?: string
};

const xxx: Example<'name', string> = { name: 'Thomas' };

const b = xxx.name; // ok, inferred as string
const x = xxx.address; // not ok
```

To avoid having to write the explicit type parameters in `Example<'name', string>`, you can use a generic identity function:

```js
function example<K extends PropertyKey, V>(e: Example<K, V>): Example<K, V> {
    return e;
}

const xxx = example({ name: 'Thomas' });
```

The constant `xxx` will be inferred to have the type `Example<'name', string>` as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic type with a union:

```js
type WithName<T> = T & { name?: string };
const myThing: WithName<{ foo?: string; bar?: number }> = { name: 'sup'};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface DictionaryLike {
    [index: string]: unknown
}

interface Example extends DictionaryLike {
  name: string;
}

const xxx: Example = { name: 'Thomas' }

const v = xxx.name; // string
const w = xxx.foo; // unknown
```